# Передача переменной на другую страницу

Tags: php, xml, get

Пытаюсь отправить переменную charName на эту страницу  `http://127.0.0.1/#/app/character?charName=Metall`  , в итоге куча ошибок. Код принимаемого файла `$charName = $_GET['charName'];
(Строка 6)$xml = simplexml_load_file("http://wow-fantasy.ru/launcher/index.php?_key=ffc312f882fbeeb51504483ee8c691a2&_url=CharInfo/" + $charName);` Знатоки, подскажите в чем проблема?  P.S пример одной из ошибок `Warning: simplexml_load_file(): I/O warning : failed to load external entity "0" in Z:\home\localhost\www\templates\character.php on line 6`

**Обновление**

А я и приложила)

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("http://wow-fantasy.ru/launcher/index.php?_key=ffc312f882fbeeb51504483ee8c691a2&_url=CharInfo/" + $charName
```

Мне нужно принять из адресной строки переменную `$charName`, которую я добавляю в свой код. Ошибку выложила. Уверена, если решить ее, то остальные решатся тоже (потому что у меня два метода подобных, но с разными переменными).

**Обновление 2**

Это все ошибки, которые возникают.

> Warning: simplexml_load_file(): I/O warning : failed to load external
>   entity "0" in character.php on line 6
>
> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in character.php on
>   line 7
>
> Warning: simplexml_load_file(): I/O warning : failed to load external
>   entity "0" in character.php on line 53
>
> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in character.php on
>   line 54

Методы идентичны - оличаются парой букв, но несут разную информацию. Все работает нормально, если я впишу вместо переменной любое имя. но вот принять переменную не получается

Comment: А вы приложите проблемный весь код сразу, чтоб не обращаться к гадалкам)

Comment: Что-то как-то мало кода с учетом ошибки `(строка 6)`

Comment: =))) Конкатенация в `php` через `.`, а не через `+` ....... должно быть, видимо `. $charName`

Comment: Очень странно... если я обращаюсь напрямую к файлу + вписываю переменную, то все нормально (правда без оформления), а так ошибки .  скрин http://hkar.ru/I0Dy

Comment: что будет если написать `"http://wow-fantasy.ru/launcher/index.php?_key=ffc312f882fbeeb51504483ee8c691a2&_url=CharInfo/" . $charName` ?

Comment: То, что я прислала на фото)

Comment: Ну дык перса с именем `1` нет........ а если попробуете `Metall`, то загрузит...... перед тем как грузить `xml` просто проверяйте что есть такой файл... типа `if (file_exists("http://wow-fantasy.ru/launcher/index.php?_key=ffc312f882fbeeb51504483ee8c691a2&_url=CharInfo/1")) {
$xml = simplexml_load_file("http://wow-fantasy.ru/launcher/index.php?_key=ffc312f882fbeeb51504483ee8c691a2&_url=CharInfo/1"); // do smth. else
}`

Comment: эм..  но переменная не должна быть единицей ()_О она должна иметь имя персонажа.  Вот код откуда я перехожу на свою страницу  `<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file("http://wow-fantasy.ru/launcher/index.php?_key=ffc312f882fbeeb51504483ee8c691a2&_url=online");
foreach($xml->Stat->CharBlock as $item)
{
$charName = $item->Name; echo ' 
                <a href="#/app/character?charName='.$charName.'" class="item item-avatar item-icon-right">
                    <img src="'.$item->Race.'">
                    <h2>'.$item->Name.'</h2>
                    <p>'.$item->Side.', '.$item->Class.'</p> </a> ';}`

Comment: Metall выдает те же ошибки.. что такое вообще..

Comment: Именно поэтому я  с самого начала попросил написать веcь код) и логику как что происходит..........решетка в `url` это так и задумано да?

Comment: Да, это уже js так делает))

Comment: Смотрите в консоль передается ли имя через параметр или нет. при выводе в цикле информации точно ли там стоят ссылки с именами, а не какие-нибудь `undefined` возможно они там уже формируются как `href="#/app/character?charName=undefined` или что-то типа такого.... отсюда и единица при передаче в другой скрипт

Comment: http://hkar.ru/I0It  вот ошибка, какого то не понятного метода.... повторюсь - если я обращаюсь напрямую к файлу и добавляю переменку вручную - все работает, видимо ошибка возникает именно в пути.. а как решить это уже иной вопрос

Comment: ну если при переходе по ссылке попадаете на нужный файл, значит путь нормальный.........вот если открыть влкадку `elements` на странице где формируются сслыки с именами, то они будут именно в стиле `#/app/character?charName=Metall`, `#/app/character?charName=Kira` и т.д. или все же в именах косяк?

Comment: `<a href="#/app/character?charName=Celestial"`  Вы правы. чтож, буду разбираться, раз в пхп все верно

Comment: @Елизавета Пожалуйста, внесите всю необходимую информацию из комментариев в тело вопроса.